# I passed a function from parent to child, implemented it onClick on the child. Getting Error: this.props.function() is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I passed a **`function`** from parent to child and implemented it onClick on the child. While clicking the button, I get the error:

> this.props.function() is not a function.

```
/* PARENT */

class User extends React.Component {

    buttonClicked(page)
    {
        this.setState({ page }, () => console.log(`NEW STATE`, this.state));
    }

    render()
    {
        return (

            <Toolbar buttonClicked={page => this.buttonClicked(page)}/>

        )
    }

}

/* CHILD */

class Toolbar extends React.Component {

render()
{
    let page = 3;
    return (

        <button value={page} onClick={page=> this.props.buttonClicked(e.target.value)}>
             {page}
        </button>        

    )

}


}
```

> Error: bundle.js:34689 Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.buttonClicked
>   is not a function at onClick (bundle.js:34689)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `buttonClicked()` with lexical binding through arrow function. Alternatively, you can [bind the function in constructor](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56).

And you access `e.target.value` from there:

```
buttonClicked = e => {
  const page = e.target.value
  // do your setState
}
```

You should pass down the function reference as props like this:

```
<Toolbar buttonClicked={buttonClicked}/>
```

In child component:

```
<button value={page} onClick={this.props.buttonClicked}>
  {page}
</button>
```

Notice that we are merely passing down the reference of `buttonClick()` function, not calling. Only when the button is clicked, the function get called with event `e`, and we can then access `e.target.value`.

[Read more about event handling in React here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this` value of the `buttonClicked` function to `this` of the parent. In your parent write this,

```
constructor(props) {
 super()

 this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not about the function but event `e` that is undefined when you use arrow function `onClick={page => this.props.buttonClicked(e.target.value)}`

```
class User extends React.Component {

  buttonClicked(page) {
    this.setState({ page }, () => console.log(`NEW STATE`, this.state));
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <Toolbar buttonClicked={page => this.buttonClicked(page)} />

    )
  }

}

/* CHILD */

class Toolbar extends React.Component {

  render() {
    let page = 3;
    return (

      <button value={page} onClick={e => this.props.buttonClicked(e.target.value)}>
        {page}
      </button>

    )

  }
}
render(<User />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pj33jo4kvj)**

Comment: The issue was unrelated to the question as I had implemented <Toolbar /> in another part of my code without passing the function as param. It's now solved. Thanks, for your time, Khatri.